# Changing the size of iPhone in xcode for story board preview

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

Can you change the size of iPhone in xcode for the story board preview from 4 inch to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can change the size to any size 
1) First goto preview mode in storyBoard
2) then at the bottom of the Preview MOde screen there is a "+" symbol click on that 
3) then a menu opens up showing all the available options select the one you need